# Eclipse: Xalan impossible due to java_cup error

Tags: eclipse, xalan

I am trying to do an xsl transformation in Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25.0) with Xalan. But starting Xalan results in an error:

```
Could not locate jar file Plugin java_cup.runtime, path null
```

There's `java_cup-runtime_0.11.20150326.v20180425-1030.jar` in my eclipse\plugins directory. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to 2023-03. The bundle name changed at one point; you'll note that java_cup.runtime != java_cup-runtime.

Comment: Oh wow, so easy...